# Why do we say 'Harry Potter fan' but 'Harry Potter's biggest fan'

Tags: adjectives, possessives

In the following constructions, why do we use an *'s* on the second option but not on the first one?

> Harry Potter fan

> Harry Potter's biggest fan

I **cannot** find any explanation for this anywhere online. Maybe I'm just not searching for it correctly, but I have no idea how to search for it.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/143199/discussion-on-question-by-patricia-fagundes-why-do-we-say-harry-potter-fan-but); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 2):

In "Harry Potter's biggest fan" there are two sets of nouns: "Harry Potter" and "fan" (specifically the "biggest fan"). The adjective can't be moved or else you're describing a large Harry Potter (like [his aunt](https://harrypotter.fandom.com/wiki/Marjorie_Dursley?file=MargeBalloon.jpg)).

In "Harry Potter fan", "Harry Potter" is a [attributive noun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_adjunct) (also called a noun adjunct, among several other names). One of the rules for attributive nouns according to [MW](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/nouns-that-look-like-adjectives) is:

> Finally, should an attributive noun be used with a real adjective, the adjective always comes first:
>
> - a long *research* paper
> - local *singles* bars

Thus, you can be the "*biggest* Harry Potter fan".

Side note: Without context, I would assume "Harry Potter fan" means a fan of the Harry Potter franchise. However, it could also mean a fan of the character specifically. For comparison, see attributive nouns that are the names of real people, such as in "[Taylor Swift fan](https://www.businessinsider.com/taylor-swift-lawyer-fans-are-organizing-against-ticketmaster-mergers-2022-11)" which only have one possible meaning.

Answer (score 0):

You would say "I am a big Harry Potter fan" or "I am the biggest Harry Potter fan" if you were talking about the franchise, whereas "I am Harry Potter's biggest fan" would imply that you were talking about Harry Potter himself.

Likewise "I am a Harry Potter fan" corresponds with "I am Harry Potter's fan."

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In their respective noun phrases,

- *biggest* is a superlative modifier
- *Harry Potter* is a complement of type
- *Harry Potter's* is a determiner.

They could all be combined, as in

> I'm Harry Potter's biggest Harry Potter fan.

If a phrase headed by a noun is to be used as determiner, it must take the form of a genitive noun phrase (*Harry Potter's*). If, on the other hand, it is to be used as a complement of type, it must take the form of a nominal *Harry Potter*, in other words  an NP with no determiner of its own, and having plain not genitive case (though sometimes genitives are allowed as in *Our largest **men's** room is over there*).

Compare:

> **This school's** biggest bus is that one. [makes clear there is specific referent - 'determines' the noun phrase]
>
> *The biggest **this school's** bus is that one. [inadmissible]
>
> *The biggest **school's** bus is that one. [inadmissible as a one-word dependent of *bus*, though could be understood as part of a determiner *The biggest school's*]
>
> The biggest **school** bus is that one. [makes clear what type of bus]